# Are there multiple endings to Portal 2's singleplayer mode?

Tags: portal-2

I could have sworn that I heard about multiple endings in Portal 2's singleplayer adventure.

> I can only find the one where my character escapes the Aperture Science testing laboratory.

Am I mad or are there actually multiple endings?

Comment: I would count the "Good Listener" achievement as an alternative ending. Admittedly, it's one that involves your death, which makes it like most of the accidental endings in the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one ending in the single player campaign, no other maps exist to allow for any sort of variation (unless you count dying as an "ending").

Most of the "multiple endings" talk thrown around online are in reference to the co-op and single player being different.

Comment: The multiple endings part refers to the bit before and after the ending song.